# A number system uses $7$ as its base. In such system, $2^{10} =$?

Tags: power-series, exponentiation, number-systems

Basically, the question asks what is:

$(2^{10})_7 = x_7$ Where x is an integer.

Now I have two questions:

1. **Is there a property wherein $(A^x)_y = (A^y)_x$?** If so, then please explain how that's possible ?
2. Had this question been $(2^8)_7 = x_7$, how would I solve it?

Comment: $x$ would be $2^{10}$ if they're both base 7.

Comment: The solution requires an Integer

Comment: Using $2^3 = 7 +1$ should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between
$(2^{10})_7$
and
$(2^{10_7})_7$.

The first is subject to
different interpretations,
depending on whether
"$10$"
is base 10 or base 7.

If base 7,
then
$10_7 = 7_{10}$
so the value is
$(2^{10_7})_7
=(2^{7_{10}})_7
=(128_{10})_7
=2x49_{10}+4x7+2
=242_7
$.

Comment: Thanks Marty, your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all my numbers are in base 10, (as @marty cohen points out we need to specify) $$2^{10} = 2 *(7+1)^3$$ You can then use the binomial theorem to expand the cube in powers of $7$ and then just do a little clean up for powers where the co-efficient exceeds $7$.

Comment: The question didn't specify this explicitly, but I guess the wording itself was pointing to Marty's interpretation.